# Перебор свойств объекта за исключением его методов

Tags: javascript

Есть объект с информацией о пользователе. В объекте есть метод, который собирает всю информацию о пользователе перебором его свойств. Нужно сделать так, чтобы перебирались все ключи объекта, за исключением тех, которые являются его методами.

```js
'use strict';

let user = {
    name: 'Alex',
    forname: 'Terel',
    yearOfBirth: 1985,
    actualYear: 2018,
    age: 32, 
    land: 'Belarus',
    city: 'Minsk',
    street: 'Victory',
    building: 76,
    calcIn: function(){
        let info = ''
        for(let key in user){
            info += this[key] + '.';
            if(typeof this[key] === 'function') break;
            
            
        }
            console.log(info)
    }
}
user.calcIn();
console.log(typeof user.calcIn)
```

Comment: как создается объект? как перебирается?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы не правильно `break` используете, да и используете его уже после того, как ключ прибавили к результату

```js
'use strict';

let user = {
    name: 'Alex',
    forname: 'Terel',
    yearOfBirth: 1985,
    actualYear: 2018,
    age: 32, 
    land: 'Belarus',
    city: 'Minsk',
    street: 'Victory',
    building: 76,
    calcIn: function(){
        const result = Object.keys(this)
            .filter(key => typeof this[key] !== 'function')
        console.log(result);
    }
}
user.calcIn();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, descriptor)**

Он позволяет объявить свойство(`prop`) объекта(`obj`) и, что самое главное, тонко настроить его особые аспекты, которые никак иначе не изменить.

**descriptor:**

**enumerable** – если true, то свойство просматривается в цикле `for..in` и методе `Object.keys()`.

```js
'use strict';

let user = {
    name: 'Alex',
    forname: 'Terel',
    yearOfBirth: 1985,
    actualYear: 2018,
    age: 32, 
    land: 'Belarus',
    city: 'Minsk',
    street: 'Victory',
    building: 76,
    calcIn: function(){
        let info = ''
        for(let key in user){
            info += this[key] + '.';
            if(typeof this[key] === 'function') break;
            
            
        }
            console.log(info)
    }
}
Object.defineProperty(user, "calcIn", {enumerable: false})
user.calcIn();
console.log(typeof user.calcIn)
```